# Logout does not work in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the following code in page.tpl.php to redirect logged-in users to the first page:

```js
if($is_front){if($user->uid != 0){header('Location:merchant-mobile');}
else{include("page-front.tpl.php"); return;}}
```

But this function conflicts with the logout function, since the logout function redirects the user to the front page, and does a logout.  How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Rules** for that or a simpler code with [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) function:

```
global $user;

if($is_front){
  if($user->uid != 0){
    header('Location:merchant-mobile');
  } else {
    drupal_goto('<front>');
  }
}
```

But why redirect a user to the frontpage if he is in the frontpage? `if($is_front)` means that the current page is frontpage. Did you mean to write `if(!$is_front)`?